# How come I can only pipe positive integers into this file?

Tags: files, sysfs

If I pipe a string consisting only of a positive integer into `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`, it works. But if I pipe a string containing anything else I've tried, I get an error message:

```
$ sudo su -c "echo 10 >/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness"
$ sudo su -c "echo -- -1 >/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness"
bash: line 0: echo: write error: Invalid argument
$ sudo su -c "echo aa >/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness"
bash: line 0: echo: write error: Invalid argument
$ sudo su -c "echo 10.2 >/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness"
bash: line 0: echo: write error: Invalid argument
```

I first thought this was some special kind of file but it appears to be a regular file:

```
$ file /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness: ASCII text
```

What's going on?

Comment: This is `sysfs`; I think there ought to be a duplicate of the question but I haven't found it so far.

Comment: Not really a duplicate but see my answer to [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/294415/controlling-display-backlight-manualy).  In summary a kernel routine is run in userspace that parses and checks what your sending to the file.

Comment: Thanks. Does the code which parses and checks what I pipe into the file running in user space cause that the error message identifies as belonging to `echo`? When I do `echo aueu > /dev/sda`, I get `bash: /dev/sda: Permission denied`, so it doesn't say that it belongs to `echo` in this case (which I find more logical at this point). Which function does the check in user space? Is it checked in kernel space, again? If I try to save an invalid value with Emacs, I get `Write error: invalid argument, /sys/[...]/brightness`, btw.

Comment: Yes, the kernel code (probably `kstrtoul` in function `bl_power_store` in file `drivers/video/backlight/backlight.c`) generates the error, which is then the result of the write syscall when performing `echo`. `Permission denied` errors are also generated by the kernel, but on the filesystem level already when trying to open the file, so much earlier, and with different error handling code in `bash`.

Comment: "generates the error" So no user space check at all? Because if there were one, execution would be aborted before the kernel got involved, wouldn't it?

Comment: Point of order regarding terminology: a _pipe_ is something that connects two programs, usually written as `program1 | program2`. The syntax using `>` is a _redirection_ (specifically, _redirecting stdout_), and **not** a pipe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only write non-negative integers to this file because it is a special file and the kernel rejects any other input. It isn't a special file in the sense of having a special file type, but it's a special file because it's on a special filesystem. When you access a “normal” filesystem, the kernel stores the file contents on a disk without interpreting them. But when you access files under `/proc` ([procfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs)) or `/sys` ([sysfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sysfs)), the data isn't stored on a disk, the access invokes custom kernel code. For a file like `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`, this custom code wants an integer between 0 and some hardware-dependent maximum, and if you try to write anything else the `write` call fails with the error status EINVAL.

Comment: Nice answer, but the maximum value can't be 100 because the current value on my laptop is 248. I think the maximum value is what's in `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/max_brightness` and that's 976 on my laptop.

Comment: @UTF-8 You're right, `max_brightness` is actually hardware-dependent, I mixed that up with the parameter to `xbacklight` which is normalized to 0–100.